# "The import org.apache.commons.fileupload cannot be resolved" does not go off despite adding lib

Tags: apache-commons-fileupload

When I try to import

```
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
```

Eclipse shows an error,

```
The import org.apache.commons.fileupload cannot be resolved
```

I added these libraries but still this error does not go off.

```
commons-fileupload-1.3.jar
commons-fileupload-1.3-javadoc.jar
commons-fileupload-1.3-sources.jar
commons-fileupload-1.3-tests.jar
commons-fileupload-1.3-test-sources.jar
```

How should I correct this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add these libraries in the build path after which it worked. Eclipse did not do it by itself.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add these libraries at 2 places. To build path of the project and in /WEB-INF/lib folder